# SoapUI Groovy - Creating Dynamic XML based on person count

Tags: xml, for-loop, soap, groovy, soapui

I'm trying to dynamically create a chunk of xml in SoapUI using Groovy scripting that outputs names, emails etc as firstnameONE, firstnameTWO etc from the count of passengers that my test passes in.

I've got as far as generating the passenger block for each passenger, per type of passenger (adult, child, infant). However I'm struggling to define the naming convention based on the count.

In addition to this the passenger XML needs to take in to consideration the passenger type it is on i.e. if it is an infant use the infant list for titles and update the  value to 'Infant'.

Here's my code so far - some of the values are passed in from test properties but you can swap for stored values:

```
numOfAdults = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("NumberOfAdults").toInteger()
numOfChildren = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("NumberOfChildren").toInteger()
numOfInfants = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("NumberOfInfants").toInteger()


totalPax = numOfAdults + numOfChildren + numOfInfants

firstName = "Firstname"
surname = "Surname"
emailAdd = "firstname" + ".surname@random.com"

adultTitle = ["Mr","Mrs","Miss","Ms"].sort{new Random()}?.take(1)[0]
infantTitle = ["Mstr","Miss"].sort{new Random()}?.take(1)[0]
gender = ["Female","Male"].sort{new Random()}?.take(1)[0]

log.info "Total Pax " + totalPax

def passengersXML = ""

def passengerXML = """
<Passenger>
    <DateOfBirth>2001-01-05T09:24:39.7911558+00:00</DateOfBirth>
    <EmailAddress>FirstNameOne.SurnameOne@random.com</EmailAddress>
    <FirstName>$firstName</FirstName>
    <Gender>$gender</Gender>
    <PassengerNum>1</PassengerNum>
    <PersonGuid>abcdefghijklmno</PersonGuid>
    <Surname>SurnameOne</Surname>
    <Title>Miss</Title>
    <Type>Adult</Type>
</Passenger>
"""

for (i = 1; i <=numOfAdults; i++){

    passengersXML += passengerXML
}
//
//
for (i = 1; i <=numOfChildren; i++){

    passengersXML += passengerXML
}
//
//
for (i = 1; i <=numOfInfants; i++){

    passengersXML += passengerXML
}


def langs = new XmlParser().parseText(passengerXML)

log.info passengersXML

testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("PassengerResponse", passengerXML)
```

Desired output:

This is an example based on 1 adult, 1 child and 1 infant but could be any number of these:

```
<Passenger>
    <DateOfBirth>2001-01-05T09:24:39.7911558+00:00</DateOfBirth>
    <EmailAddress>FirstNameOne.SurnameOne@random.com</EmailAddress>
    <FirstName>$firstNameOne</FirstName>
    <Gender>$gender</Gender>
    <PassengerNum>1</PassengerNum>
    <PersonGuid>abcdefghijklmno</PersonGuid>
    <Surname>SurnameOne</Surname>
    <Title>Miss</Title>
    <Type>Adult</Type>
</Passenger>
<Passenger>
    <DateOfBirth>2001-01-05T09:24:39.7911558+00:00</DateOfBirth>
    <EmailAddress>FirstNameTwo.SurnameTwo@random.com</EmailAddress>
    <FirstName>$firstNameTwo</FirstName>
    <Gender>$gender</Gender>
    <PassengerNum>2</PassengerNum>
    <PersonGuid>abcdefghijklmno</PersonGuid>
    <Surname>SurnameTwo</Surname>
    <Title>Mr</Title>
    <Type>Child</Type>
</Passenger>
<Passenger>
    <DateOfBirth>2001-01-05T09:24:39.7911558+00:00</DateOfBirth>
    <EmailAddress>FirstNameThree.SurnameThree@random.com</EmailAddress>
    <FirstName>$firstNameThree</FirstName>
    <Gender>$gender</Gender>
    <PassengerNum>3</PassengerNum>
    <PersonGuid>abcdefghijklmno</PersonGuid>
    <Surname>SurnameThree</Surname>
    <Title>Miss</Title>
    <Type>Infant</Type>
</Passenger>
```

Comment: Do you need to send every thing in single request? What is the expected output out of groovy script? Please updated the question addressing these questions.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I basically want the xml block in the example repeated by the amount of passengers passed in another soap request but with the names updating based on passenger number i.e. passengerOne, passengerTwo etc The xml will then be passed in to another Soap request. In addition each repeated block of xml has to distinguish between the passenger type specified in the various passenger types set in the test case properties (beginning of the code block)

Comment: I think I know what you mean now. Do you mean can I split the xml in to 3 separate blocks i.e. one for adult, child and infant? This is a possibility however I still need to pass to the Soap request as one value.

Comment: Can you please show the desired output in full request?

Comment: Updated original question

Comment: But that is not a valid xml, right?

Comment: Yes it is. It might not look valid as I haven't provided the full XML which for this question isn't important. The intention is that this block will be passed in to a larger block of xml...It's just that I need to build the <passenger> block dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get to the bottom of this and answered my own query. There is possibly a better way but this is how I achieved what I wanted for my end result:

```
import static java.util.UUID.randomUUID 


numOfAdults = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("NumberOfAdults").toInteger()
numOfChildren = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("NumberOfChildren").toInteger()
numOfInfants = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("NumberOfInfants").toInteger()
paxNumber = ["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen","twenty"]

totalPax = numOfAdults + numOfChildren + numOfInfants

firstName = "Firstname"
surname = "Surname"
emailAdd = firstName + "." + surname + "@random.com"

passengersXML = ""

for (i = 1; i <=numOfAdults; i++){
    paxNum = i
    firstName = firstName + paxNumber[i-1]
    surname = surname + paxNumber[i-1]
    guid = randomUUID() as String
    adultTitle = ["Mr","Mrs","Miss","Ms"].sort{new Random()}?.take(1)[0] 
    gender = ["Female","Male"].sort{new Random()}?.take(1)[0]
    passengerAdultXML = """
                        <Passenger>
                            <DateOfBirth>2001-01-05T09:24:39.7911558+00:00</DateOfBirth>
                            <EmailAddress>$firstName.$surname@random.com</EmailAddress>
                            <FirstName>$firstName</FirstName>
                            <Gender>$gender</Gender>
                            <PassengerNum>$paxNum</PassengerNum>
                            <PersonGuid>$guid</PersonGuid>
                            <Surname>$surname</Surname>
                            <Title>$adultTitle</Title>
                            <Type>Adult</Type>
                        </Passenger>
                    """
    firstName = "Firstname"
    surname = "Surname"
    passengersXML += passengerAdultXML
}
//
//
for (i = 1; i <=numOfChildren; i++){
    paxNum = numOfAdults + i
    i = paxNum
    firstName = firstName + paxNumber[i-1]
    surname = surname + paxNumber[i-1]
    guid = randomUUID() as String
    adultTitle = ["Mr","Mrs","Miss","Ms"].sort{new Random()}?.take(1)[0]
    gender = ["Female","Male"].sort{new Random()}?.take(1)[0]
    passengerChildXML = """
                        <Passenger>
                            <DateOfBirth>2001-01-05T09:24:39.7911558+00:00</DateOfBirth>
                            <EmailAddress>$firstName.$surname@random.com</EmailAddress>
                            <FirstName>$firstName</FirstName>
                            <Gender>$gender</Gender>
                            <PassengerNum>$paxRPH</PassengerNum>
                            <PersonGuid>$guid</PersonGuid>
                            <Surname>$surname</Surname>
                            <Title>$adultTitle</Title>
                            <Type>Child</Type>
                        </Passenger>
                    """
    firstName = "Firstname"
    surname = "Surname"
    passengersXML += passengerChildXML
}
//
//
for (i = 1; i <=numOfInfants; i++){
    paxNum = numOfAdults + numOfChildren + i
    i = paxNum
    firstName = firstName + paxNumber[i-1]
    surname = surname + paxNumber[i-1]
    guid = randomUUID() as String
    infantTitle = ["Master","Miss"].sort{new Random()}?.take(1)[0]
    gender = ["Female","Male"].sort{new Random()}?.take(1)[0]
    passengerInfantXML = """
                        <Passenger>
                            <DateOfBirth>2001-01-05T09:24:39.7911558+00:00</DateOfBirth>
                            <EmailAddress>$firstName.$surname@random.com</EmailAddress>
                            <FirstName>$firstName</FirstName>
                            <Gender>$gender</Gender>
                            <PassengerNum>$paxRPH</PassengerNum>
                            <PersonGuid>$guid</PersonGuid>
                            <Surname>$surname</Surname>
                            <Title>$infantTitle</Title>
                            <Type>Infant</Type>
                        </Passenger>
                    """
    firstName = "Firstname"
    surname = "Surname"
    passengersXML += passengerInfantXML
}

log.info passengersXML

testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("PassengerResponse", passengersXML)
```

The output is as follows:

```
<Passenger>
    <DateOfBirth>2001-01-05T09:24:39.7911558+00:00</DateOfBirth>
    <EmailAddress>Firstnameone.Surnameone@random.com</EmailAddress>
    <FirstName>Firstnameone</FirstName>
    <Gender>Female</Gender>
    <PassengerNum>1</PassengerNum>
    <PersonGuid>cf2f384b-9f99-4846-a774-f044d309b603</PersonGuid>
    <Surname>Surnameone</Surname>
    <Title>Mrs</Title>
    <Type>Adult</Type>
</Passenger>

<Passenger>
    <DateOfBirth>2001-01-05T09:24:39.7911558+00:00</DateOfBirth>
    <EmailAddress>Firstnametwo.Surnametwo@random.com</EmailAddress>
    <FirstName>Firstnametwo</FirstName>
    <Gender>Female</Gender>
    <PassengerNum>2</PassengerNum>
    <PersonGuid>aa01d2e4-c77d-42fc-b9f0-ed8487ba3cc0</PersonGuid>
    <Surname>Surnametwo</Surname>
    <Title>Miss</Title>
    <Type>Adult</Type>
</Passenger>

<Passenger>
    <DateOfBirth>2001-01-05T09:24:39.7911558+00:00</DateOfBirth>
    <EmailAddress>Firstnamethree.Surnamethree@random.com</EmailAddress>
    <FirstName>Firstnamethree</FirstName>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
    <PassengerNum>3</PassengerNum>
    <PersonGuid>8132e6f8-f235-4d74-9f87-ebc88cf27ed6</PersonGuid>
    <Surname>Surnamethree</Surname>
    <Title>Mrs</Title>
    <Type>Adult</Type>
</Passenger>

<Passenger>
    <DateOfBirth>2001-01-05T09:24:39.7911558+00:00</DateOfBirth>
    <EmailAddress>Firstnamefour.Surnamefour@random.com</EmailAddress>
    <FirstName>Firstnamefour</FirstName>
    <Gender>Female</Gender>
    <PassengerNum>4</PassengerNum>
    <PersonGuid>a351a827-c273-4cbf-8537-a3fd20b80464</PersonGuid>
    <Surname>Surnamefour</Surname>
    <Title>Mr</Title>
    <Type>Child</Type>
</Passenger>
```